# Как установить Microsoft Visual Installer который не устанавливается?

Tags: visual-studio

У меня такая ситуация. Windows 7 x64 sp1, без обновлений. Пробовал ставить VS17 и VS19. Запускаю инсталлятор vs_Community.exe, он говорит, что перед началом нужно кое-что настроить. Скачивает 70Мб из интернета, что-то с минуту устанавливает и просто закрывается. В диспетчере задач ничего, относящегося к установке VS, не остаётся. В %TEMP% пишет небольшие логи из которых видно, что инсталлятор отработал без ошибок.
В папке C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\ появляется файлик vs_installershell.exe, если его запустить, открывается окно Visual Studio Installer, которое пишет, что у вас ничего не установлено и предлагает заново скачать файл vs_Community.exe.

Comment: Почитайте требования https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements

Answer (score 1):

Значит так,что бы Visual installer заработал он требует что бы Windows загрузила KB2919355, KB2932046, KB2959977, KB2937592, KB2938439, KB2934018 такие обновления и в этом порядке, 
Решил проблему просто включив обновления и поставил комп включенным на ночь, утром проснулся перезагрузил комп и всё работает! Ответ: Загрузите начальные обновления Win7.

Answer (score 1):

У меня было тоже самое, он даже не запускался выдавая ошибку, при том что стояли все последние обновления. Откатился на 2 месяца - всё равно такая же проблема. Помогла переустановка .Net runtime и Visual C++ 15-19 redistributable.

P.S. В итоге через недельку после установки открыл инсталлер v 2.9.3365 - он крашится без ошибки вообще, зато хотя бы запускается. Пытался сделать как [тут](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-Installer-crashes-after-up/1356122) - не помогает